# MongoDB group by date and fill zero counts

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to group my search results by date. The results are then also counted.

```
var fromDate = new Date(req.query.fromDate);
var toDate = new Date(req.query.toDate);

global.databaseStatistic.collection(global.ARTICLEPRESS).aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            article: { $in: articleIdArray },
            date: { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "date": {
                    $dateToString: { format: "%d.%m.%Y", date: "$date" }
                }
            }, 
            "count": { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

This works perfectly, but I would also like to show all days that have a count of zero. It should be so displayed every day within an interval, also having a count of zero. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it looks very trivial - it is not.

There is no way to have a reference sequence to compare with, even `$lookup` cannot help as this a kind of inner join type.

The way you could have this done is a kind of post process of result-set returned to mongoose.

The steps I have in mind could be:

1. create array of dates from `req.query.fromDate` to `req.query.toDate` formated in the same way as in query
2. remove entries in array which we have in result set
3. merge our array with `count:0` and date
4. sort results (if needed)

any comments welcome!

Comment: That's what I have now done on the client side. It's really a pity that there is no way to do this directly in MongoDB. I hope that may once there is an update that this feature provides.Thank you

Comment: @laren0815 I'm lookig forward for same :-) as sql boys have some stuff `(tmpTables, cte)` that could solve this server side :P